# Redmine Custom Field not showing in Issue

Tags: redmine, custom-fields

I have some Custom fields that are no longer visible on an Issue page. If I go to edit the issue I can edit the custom field, but from just the view you can no longer see it at the top with all the other fields. I am certain this used to work so I am sure I've made a mistake in settings somewhere recently, but I cannot for the life of me find it!

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with reviewing that custom field's settings in Redmine > Administration > Custom fields  and open detail of the field you're after. Next, review [image: the visibility settings]

Whether you see the field or not may depend on:
- your user's role
- type of tracker that you're using
- project that you're in

For instance, in my screenshot only developers see a certain custom field if an issue is bug in a specific project (not any project in our Redmine).